# Given two minimal FSMs with one accepting a subset of the other, must a simulation exist?

Tags: automata

As part of an example, Abstract and Concrete Categories, section 3.35, claims:

> For every two minimal [by number of states] $\Sigma$-acceptors $A$ and $A'$, there exists at most one simulation $A \to A'$, and such a simulation exists if and only if $A'$ accepts each word accepted by $A$.

(A $\Sigma$-acceptor is defined the same way as an FSM is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine#Mathematical_model), with $\Sigma$ automatically filling the language slot.  A simulation $A \to A'$ is a function between the states of $A$ and $A'$ that preserves transitions, initial state, and finishing states.)

Suppose $\Sigma$ is $\{a,b,c\}$ and $A$ and $A'$ are languages denoted by the regular expressions `a*` and `[ab]*` respectively.  The minimal acceptors seem to be as follows:

```
A:
    Q = {S,E}
    delta(A, S) = S
    delta(x, y) = E
    initial = S
    accepting = S

A' same, except:
    delta'(x, E) = E
    delta'(C, y) = E
    delta'(x, y) = S
```

However, none of the four functions $\{S,E\} \to \{S,E\}$ give a valid simulation.   Am I missing some sort of condition, or misunderstanding the guarantee?

Comment: This would be ok modulo accepting states, however, consider a one-state automatas, one for $L_1 = \Sigma^*$ and the second $L_2 = \varnothing$. Surely, $L_2 \subset L_1$, but there is no way any function $A_2 \to A_1$ would preserve accepting states.